# Create X shape layout using 5 elements

Tags: html, css, css-float

So my task is to align 5 divs to be positioned in an X position:

```css
body{
  height:300px;
  width: 300px;
}

div{
  height:100px;
  width:100px;
  float:left;
  background:black;
  overflow: none;
}

div:nth-child(2) {
    margin-left: 100px;
}
div:nth-child(3) {
    margin-left: 100px;
    margin-right: 100px;
}
div:nth-child(5) {
    margin-left: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div>
</div>
<div>
</div>
<div>
</div>
<div>
</div>
<div>
</div>
```

As you can see I already aligned them. I can't use any other additional elements, only 5 divs. But I have a feeling that there is a more elegant solution, with less lines of css. Would be nice to see the best solution :)

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;  /* align items to edges, horizontally */
  align-content: space-between;    /* align items to edges, vertically */
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
}

div {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background: black;
}

div:nth-child(2) {
  position: relative;              /* in-flow positioning */
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
```

### [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nqpvqutg/1/)